# Fourier series of $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x\ln(x)^2}$ on $[0,a]$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

I am looking for the Fourier series of

$$f : x \mapsto \frac{1}{x|\ln(x)|^2}$$
defined (and periodically extended to $\mathbb{R}$) on $[0,a]$ with $a <1$. The Fourier series does exist since $f \in L^1([0,a])$ using Bertrand integrale $\int_0^a \frac{1}{x^\alpha \ln(x)^\beta} < +\infty \iff (\alpha < 1) \text{ or } (\alpha=1 \text{ and } \beta>1)$.

So I'm trying concretely to compute, for a fixed $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, the coefficient $n$ of the Fourier series :

$$c_n(f) = \int_0^a \frac{e^{-\frac{i 2 \pi x n}{a}}}{x \ln(x)^2} \ \mathrm{d}x$$

Do you have any ideas on how to proceed ?

Comment: I don't think the integral converges because of the singularity at $x=1$

Comment: You're right, to avoid this problem I have changed a little bit the space where I compute the integral.

Comment: Have you tried integrating

Comment: Do you want the Fourier series, not transform? Or do you want the Fourier transform of the extension of your function to all of $\mathbb{R}$ where it is $0$ outside of $[0,a]$?

Comment: I'll edit my question accordingly, I'm in fact looking for the Fourier Series.

Comment: I think you want $e^{-2\pi inx/a}$, not $e^{-inx}$, to make things periodic with period $a$.